# fancybox afterclose callback from within the fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to click on a link within the fancybox when it gets closed.

is that possible?

I can only seem to be able to access DOM elements from the parent window, not the fancybox itself.

Comment: what kind of fancybox div/iframe ?

Comment: What does clicking the link do? In other words, could you not just call that function onclose of the fancybox?

Comment: the clicking of the link opens a facebook share popup. The reason why I want to do it within the fancybox is because the fancybox consists of 2 pages (one redirects to the other one) and I only want the facebook share popup to come up on the second page. so if the user opens the fancybox and closes it without getting to the second page the facebook share won't launch